# Removing '\n' and ' ' from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

My requirement is to send the JSON object created from the nested dictionary which has the characters like '\n' and ' '. Below is the dictionary which I am trying to change.

```
{'item': [{'Sno': 1,
'Item Code / Product Description': 'TGMOCL0015 / CORSAIR MOUSE, M55 RGB PRO, PART# CH-9308011-AP',
'HSN / SAC\nCode': '8471.60.60',
'Quantity': 7,
'Unit Price\n[INR]': 1741,
'Total\n[INR]': 12187,
'Rate': 18,
'IGST [INR]\nAmount': 2193.66,
'Line Total\n[INR]': 14380.66},
{'Sno': 2,
'Item Code / Product Description': 'TGMOCL0013 / CORSAIR MOUSE, HARPOON PRO-BLK-RGB, PART#CH-9301111-AP',
'HSN / SAC\nCode': '8471.60.60',
'Quantity': 8,
'Unit Price\n[INR]': 1200,
'Total\n[INR]': 9600,
'Rate': 18,
'IGST [INR]\nAmount': 1728.0,
'Line Total\n[INR]': 11328.0},
{'Sno': 3,
'Item Code / Product Description': 'TGCBCL0029 / CORSAIR CABINET SPEC-05, BLK - PART# CC-9011138-WW',
'HSN / SAC\nCode': '8473.30.99',
'Quantity': 37,
'Unit Price\n[INR]': 2225,
'Total\n[INR]': 82325,
'Rate': 18,
'IGST [INR]\nAmount': 14818.5,
'Line Total\n[INR]': 97143.5},
{'Sno': 4,
'Item Code / Product Description': 'TGHSCL0003 / CORSAIR GAMING HEADSET HS50 Stereo Carbon PART# CA-9011170-AP',
'HSN / SAC\nCode': '8518.30.00',
'Quantity': 92,
'Unit Price\n[INR]': 3000,
'Total\n[INR]': 276000,
'Rate': 18,
'IGST [INR]\nAmount': 49680.0,
'Line Total\n[INR]': 325680.0},
{'Sno': 5,
'Item Code / Product Description': 'TGMOCL0001 / CORSAIR MOUSE,HARPOON-BLK-RGB, PART#CH-9301011-AP',
'HSN / SAC\nCode': '8471.60.60',
'Quantity': 43,
'Unit Price\n[INR]': 1018,
'Total\n[INR]': 43774,
'Rate': 18,
'IGST [INR]\nAmount': 7879.32,
'Line Total\n[INR]': 51653.32},
{'Sno': 6,
'Item Code / Product Description': 'TGKBCL0001 / CORSAIR KEYBOARD K95 PLTN-BLK-MX Speed-RGB PART# CH-9127014-NA',
'HSN / SAC\nCode': '8471.60.40',
'Quantity': 8,
'Unit Price\n[INR]': 10750,
'Total\n[INR]': 86000,
'Rate': 18,
'IGST [INR]\nAmount': 15480.0,
'Line Total\n[INR]': 101480.0},
{'Sno': 7,
'Item Code / Product Description': 'TGKBCL0007 / CORSAIR KEYBOARD K55-BLK-RBRDME-RGB PART# CH-9206015-NA',
'HSN / SAC\nCode': '8471.60.40',
'Quantity': 14,
'Unit Price\n[INR]': 2400,
'Total\n[INR]': 33600,
'Rate': 18,
'IGST [INR]\nAmount': 6048.0,
'Line Total\n[INR]': 39648.0}]}
```

The problem is I am getting the keys like:

```
'Item Code / Product Description'
'HSN / SAC\nCode'
'Unit Price\n[INR]'
'Total\n[INR]'
'IGST [INR]\nAmount'
'Line Total\n[INR]'
```

But it should be like this:

```
'ItemCode/ProductDescription'
'HSN/SACCode'
'UnitPrice[INR]'
'Total[INR]'
'IGST[INR]Amount'
'LineTotal[INR]'
```

I have tried the below code but its not working:

```
res2 = {x: v.replace(' ','') 
    for x, v in res2.items()}
res2 = {x: v.replace('\n','') 
    for x, v in res2.items()}
```

Error is below:

```
 9 #key, value = list(res2.items())[0]
 10 res2 = {x: v.replace(' ','') 
---> 11 for x, v in res2.items()}
     12 res2 = {x: v.replace('\n','') 
     13 for x, v in res2.items()}





AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry for the mistakes if I have done while editing.

Comment: What is the value of `res2`. Please share the code where you assign value to it

Comment: @CodePope the dictionary above is the value of res2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rebuild the whole thing with:

```
n = {"item": []}
for i in d["item"]:
    n["item"].append({k.strip().replace("\n", ""): v for k, v in i.items()})
```

Or a one-liner:

```
{"item": [{k.strip().replace("\n", ""): v for k, v in i.items()} for i in d["item"]]}
```

where `d` is your data structure.

Output of

```
print(json.dumps({"item": [{k.strip().replace("\n", ""): v for k, v in i.items()} for i in d["item"]]}, indent=4))
```

```
{
    "item": [
        {
            "Sno": 1,
            "Item Code / Product Description": "TGMOCL0015 / CORSAIR MOUSE, M55 RGB PRO, PART# CH-9308011-AP",
            "HSN / SACCode": "8471.60.60",
            "Quantity": 7,
            "Unit Price[INR]": 1741,
            "Total[INR]": 12187,
            "Rate": 18,
            "IGST [INR]Amount": 2193.66,
            "Line Total[INR]": 14380.66
        },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to convert the entire thing to a string, replace `\n` and spaces with blanks, and convert it back to a `dict`.

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval(str(x).replace('\\n','').replace(' ',''))
print(x['item'][0].keys())

dict_keys(['Sno', 'ItemCode/ProductDescription', 'HSN/SACCode', 'Quantity', 'UnitPrice[INR]', 'Total[INR]', 'Rate', 'IGST[INR]Amount', 'LineTotal[INR]'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get the required keys.

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you get is because you have not just dictionaries, but also lists.

In general, when dealing with a nested structure, the most natural fit will be a recursive function; something like this:

```py
def remove_key_whitespace(o):
  if isinstance(o, dict):
    return {
        k.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', ''): remove_key_whitespace(v)
        for k, v in o.items()
    }
  elif isinstance(o, list):
    return [remove_key_whitespace(item) for item in o]
  else:
    return o
```